Take a snapshot of UITextView inside UITableViewCell
I'm trying to take a snapshot of UITextView inside UITableViewCell.The code is as below.
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

　　　　　 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

　　　　　 func bind(){
         let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.myTextView.bounds.size)
         let myImage = renderer.image { (context) in
           var bounds = self.myTextView.bounds
           bounds.origin = CGPoint.zero
           self.myTextView.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
         }
   }

}

bind() is called as below.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath ) as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.bind()
}


However, the following error occurs and myImage becomes nil.
[Snapshotting] View (UITextView) drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported.

If afterScreenUpdates is set to false, the following error will occur.
[Snapshotting] Rendering a view (UITextView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

I tried the following as an alternative method, but myImage still becomes nil.
let rect = self.myTextView.bounds
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
self.myTextView.layer.render(in: context)
let myImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Thank you for your comment. I have added the points you pointed out to the text.

The goal is to blur the textView inside tableviewCell. In the process, I'm trying to take a snapshot of textView and blur that image.

With UIVisualEffectView, it is not possible to blur the characters in textView, and the characters  disappear. So I'm trying to take a snapshot and blur it out.

How about myTextView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext) instead of drawHierarchy? It doesn't do exactly the same thing, but might nevertheless be suitable for your situation.

I tried myTextView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext) , but myImage remains nil. The detailed code has been added to the text.
